# Track changes for a given field given some ID and date

Tags: r, loops, time-series, aggregate

I have the following dataframe:

[image: Input table]

Each client's cap could be upgraded at some point in time defined by column Date. I would like to aggregate on ID and show on what date the cap has been upgraded. Sometimes this could happen twice. The output should look like this:

[image: Output table]

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
  Cap = c("S", "S", "M", "S", "M", "L", "L", "S", "L"),
  Date = paste("01", c(1:2, 4, 3:6, 2:3), "2000") %>% lubridate::dmy()
)


df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% # looking at each ID separately
  mutate(prev = lag(Cap), # what is the row - 1 value
         change = !(Cap == prev)) %>% # is the row - 1 value different than the current row value
  filter(change) %>% # filtering where there are changes
  select(ID, "From" = prev, "To" = Cap, Date) # renaming columns and selecting the relevant ones
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lag` command here to create a column with the previous rows value of Cap included. Then you simply filter out first entries and rows which are the same.

```
out <- dat %>%
  ## calculate lag within unique subjects
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    ## copy previous row value to new column
    from=lag(Cap),
    to=Cap
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ## ignore first entry for each subject
  drop_na(from) %>%
  ## ignore all rows where Cap didn't change
  filter(from != to) %>% 
  ## reorder columns
  select(ID, from, to, Date)
```

This gives us output matching your expected format

```
> out
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     ID from  to     Date
  <dbl> <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1     1 S     M         4
2     2 S     M         4
3     2 M     L         5
4     3 S     L         3
```